# Auto-binding templates with function (Polymer 1.x)

Tags: templates, data-binding, polymer, polymer-1.0

Hello I have this simple index file:

```
<?php use Cake\Routing\Router; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <link rel="import" href="<?= Router::url('/'); ?>bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <?php echo $this->Html->script('/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js'); ?>
</head>
<body unresolved>
<template id="app" is="dom-bind" >
    <h1 on-click="{{stateChange}}">Holaaa</h1>
</template>
<script>
    var app = document.querySelector('#app');
    app.stateChange= function(){
        console.log("stateChange");
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
[dom-bind::_createEventHandler]: listener method `{{stateChange}}` not defined
```

I have a working app with Polymer where everything works nicely. But this simple example is not working! Why!?

Why? What did I miss?

I have tried defining the stateChange function with app. and without the app. too with no success.

I have also tried wrapping it in dom change event like the documentation points out but not working

```
app.addEventListener('dom-change', function() {
    stateChange= function(){
        console.log("stateChange");
    };
});
```

I have tried defining the stateChange function iside the dom-change event with app. with this. and without anything. Nothing works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the curly brackets.

```
<h1 on-click="stateChange">Holaaa</h1>
```

> **Compatibility note**: The syntax differs from 0.5, which required curly brackets ({{}}) around the event handler name.

Source: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html#annotated-listeners